# mysqli displaying database information

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I am trying to display the database information that I have retrieved from the query below. It displays reports uploaded by a user and it only displays the reports that particular user has uploaded. It is using a session variable that holds the user login name which is the same as the userID.

```
<?php



        function getUploadedReports($user) {
        $conn = new mysqli(localhost, root, DBPASS, DBNAME);
        $reports = array();
        $user        = $_SESSION['sess_uid'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE userID = '" . $conn->real_escape_string($user)."';";
        // Performs the $sql query on the server
        $maincat = $conn->query($sql);

        while($row = $maincat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            // do something with the $row
            array_push($reports, $row);

        }

        echo $reports;

       }


        ?>
```

However I am getting a blank result and within the database the particular user i'm logged in as has uploaded 2 reports. I am trying to echo the information onto the webpage, however I also thought about going down the route of placing the result on a table of sorts. However at the moment I am just content getting the information to echo on the page.

A second pair of eyes would be a great help as the solution to my issue isn't clear .

Comment: are u sure ur session data is available ? make sure to use session_start() on the top.

Comment: echo the query and run it in eg phpmyadmin or navicat. Does it return anything?

Comment: ill try and report back

Comment: Then your problem is in your query.. Should there be something returned (is the query correct)?

Comment: having ran the query "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE userID = 'insertusername' I am returned 2 rows which I expected to see

Comment: It must be something to do with my array I am creating

Comment: I always loop using `fetch_assoc()` maybe you could try that. Also use  print_r or var_dump to show the contents of $reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [**session_start()**](https://www.php.net/session_start) in your code

```
        <?php
//here> session_start();
```

Comment: added session_start(); although nothing has changed as of yet

Comment: i am able to echo my session variable so there is no issue with the session